# VS2013 & TFS2012: Cannot create Team Project from outside of LAN (TF400324)

Tags: networking, visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server

VS is 2013 Update 2. TFS Version is 12.0.21005.1 (Tfs2013.RTM), might it need an update? If not here goes:

Creating Team Projects from inside my Home Network, where the Server with TFS2012 is located as 'fgnd-server', works fine. When I try the same from outside the LAN (we have dyndns and port 30111, used for TFS, is forwarded etc...). Note that connecting to collections and downloading projects, checking in changes etc. from outside the LAN works fine, so I wouldnt know of any firewall settings or so that could be responsible.
The error is:

```
TF218027: The following reporting folder could not be created on the server
that is running SQL Server Reporting Services: /TfsReports/Test Collection.
The report server is located at: http://fgnd-server/Reports. The error is:
TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from the server.
Technical information (for administrator):
  The remote name could not be resolved: 'fgnd-server'. Verify that the path
  is correct and that you have sufficient permissions to create a folder on
  that server, and then try again...
```

Edit: I wonder about the 'remote name: 'fgnd-server'', since that would be the LAN adress. I am not sure where anything tries to reach that adress, maybe something in VS?

Edit 2: This might be related: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64ce135f-8269-4db5-976c-3b22eb3b3ef1/tf218017-tf218027-cannot-create-project-on-tfs-2010-from-visual-studio-2010?forum=tfsgeneral but I am (right now) not able to make the changes mentioned as solution in that thread.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  Its can't resolve the address your providing it which indicates it cannot be reached from outside of the LAN.

Comment: The question is why it cannot resolve it. As stated, the server is resolved properly when e.g. connecting to project collections.

Comment: You know more about your network than we do.  Can you ping the address from outside of the LAN?

Comment: Are the TFS application tier and the TFS data tier both installed on the same server? The reports 'http://fgnd-server/Reports' are hosted in reporting services on port 80. TFS is hosted in IIS and is typically on port 8080. Sharepoint (if you're using it) is hosted in IIS on port 80. If all 3 products are installed on the same server then it's likely that the ports may be different (you'll need to check this). To be able to create a new team project you will need access to all 3 web sites so you'll need to do port forwarding for all 3.

Comment: @JamesReed: Yes, both run on the same server. Thanks, I'll have a closer look at port 80. I know I forwarded 8080, and I'm not using Sharepoint.

Comment: @JamesReed: ReportServer and Reports, as well as TFS are acessible from outside LAN via browser. I think the problem might be that in TFS Administration Console -> Application Tier -> Reporting -> Edit -> Reports -> URLs for Report Server, the URLs are 'http://fgnd-server/ReportServer' for Web Service and 'http://fgnd-server/Reports' for Report Manager. I think Visual Studio is told those URLs and of course cannot resolve them unless inside LAN...